# Proof of the Cauchy–Hadamard theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, power-series

I'm looking at the proof of Cauchy–Hadamard theorem.

Let $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n$ be a power series where $a_n\in\mathbb{R}, z\in\mathbb{C}$. Let t = $\limsup|a_n|^{1/n}$, and let R = the radius of convergence of this series. Then,

(i) $t \in\left(0,\infty\right)  \Longrightarrow 1/R = t$

(ii) $t = 0 \Longrightarrow R=\infty$

(iii) $t = \infty \Longrightarrow R = 0$

I'm struggling to prove the case (iii) which says that if the sequence $\{|a_n|^{1/n}\}$ is unbounded, then the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n$ converges absolutely only for $z = 0$.  Similar question have already been asked in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092022/cauchy-hadamard-formula-proof). But there is no proof for the case (iii). I tried to prove that if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nz^n$ converges absolutely for some $z \neq 0$, then this leads to a contradiction. But this approach didn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This follows directly from the root test for absolute convergence. If $t = \infty$ then $$\limsup_n \sqrt[n]{|a_nz^n|} = \limsup_n |z|\sqrt[n]{|a_n|} = \infty > 1$$
as long as $z\neq 0$, which implies divergence. [This trivially follows from the divergence $\sum q^n$ for $q>1$.]

Comment: I appreciate your help in resolving the problem!